# Set string empty text when SelectedDate is certain value DatePicker WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

In my project I have a min value datetime that is 01/01/1900. In my datepicker, if the SelectedDate is 01/01/1900 I want to show string empty text or anything else text, but not "01/01/1900". Is it possible with wpf datepicker to change ONLY text and not change the SelectedDate? Result I want: i.e datePicker.Text = "" AND datePicker.SelectedDate = 01/01/1900 at same time. Thanks for reply

Comment: You can do Visibility toggle stuff. For example if the date user provided - was not you want to show, just change visibility of datePicker control, and show another control with something. You can achieve this in different ways, but visibility is most common stuff which comes in mind first for me.

Comment: what about editing the template of the datepicker and add a trigger that hides your text whenever the date is 01/01/1900